# Hatch a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I use this code in order to generate a graph:

And I must to hatch everything outside the square.

```
pos = [3.75 5.6 53.5 29.5];  %spatiul nemasurat
axis([0 61 0 45]) %axele
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'0', '7.5','11.85', '16.2', '20.55', '24.9', '29.25', '33.6', '39.3', '45'})

rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','black')
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: Can you be more clear? How do you want it to look like? ( fun fact: as a non native english speaker I didn't know that meaning of hatch, I as just wondering what Matlab as to do with eggs)

Comment: I think by "hatch" the OP means "lines running across the area to shade it". OP - can you confirm that please?

Comment: I want something like this to appear outside the square http://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/fillpattern.html More specific I want Diagonal Lines outside the square. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a function `hatch_coordinates` which can return hatch pattern coordinates (*get the code at the bottom of the anwser*). With that, you simply plot your hatch pattern on you axis, then you plot your rectangle on top of it. You have to set the face color of the rectangle to hide the pattern behind.

```
xlim = [0 61] ;
ylim = [0 45] ;
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim ) ; %// this return coordinates to plot a hatch pattern
plot(X,Y,'k')                              %// and this simply plot the pattern, with the attributes you want (color, linespec, etc ...)
hold on ; grid off

pos = [3.75 5.6 53.5 29.5];  %spatiul nemasurat
axis([0 61 0 45]) %axele
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'0', '7.5','11.85', '16.2', '20.55', '24.9', '29.25', '33.6', '39.3', '45'})
rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','black','FaceColor','w')
```

That will give you:
[image: hatchedfig]

---

Note that the hatching can be varied in multiple ways. The angle can be set by changing the ratio `xstep`/`ystep`, and all the `LineStyle` properties are available.
Quick example of a few variations:

```
xl = [0 5] ; yl = [0 5] ;

%// simple hatch, angle changed
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xl , yl , 0.2 ) ;
subplot(1,4,1) ; plot(X,Y) ; grid off

%// heavy line hatching
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xl , yl , 0.5 ) ;
subplot(1,4,2) ; plot(X,Y,'k','linewidth',2) ;grid off

%// very light color hatching, flatter angle, dotted lines
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xl , yl , 1 , 0.1 ) ;
subplot(1,4,3) ; plot(X,Y,'Color',[.7 .7 .7],'linewidth',1,'LineStyle',':') ;grid off

%// multi color hatching, (specify option "merge=false" )
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xl , yl , 0.5 , 0.5 , false ) ;
subplot(1,4,4) ; plot(X,Y) ;grid off
```

[image: multihatch]

---

### Code:

function `hatch_coordinates.m` :

```
function [X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim , xstep , ystep , merge )
%// function [X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim , xstep , ystep , merge )
%//
%// Return coordinates for plotting a hatch pattern
%// The angle of the lines can be adjusted by varying the ratio xstep/ystep
%// xlim and ylim are vectors with two elements, where the first element needs to be smaller than the second.

%% // set default options
if nargin < 3 ; xstep = 1     ; end
if nargin < 4 ; ystep = xstep ; end
if nargin < 5 ; merge = true  ; end

%% // define base grid
xpos = xlim(1):xstep:xlim(2) ; nx = numel(xpos) ;
ypos = ylim(1):ystep:ylim(2) ; ny = numel(ypos) ;

%% // Create the coordinates
nanline = NaN*ones(1,nx+ny-3) ;
X = [ [ xpos(1)*ones(1,ny-2) xpos(1:end-1) ] ; ...
      [ xpos(2:end) xpos(end)*ones(1,ny-2) ] ; ...
      nanline ] ;
Y = [ [ypos(end-1:-1:1) ylim(1)*ones(1,nx-2) ]  ; ...
      [ypos(end)*ones(1,nx-1) ypos(end-1:-1:2)] ; ...
      nanline ] ;

%% // merge if asked too
if merge
    X = X(:) ;
    Y = Y(:) ;
end
```

Comment: @Ştefan. Thanks for feedback. If this question was solved, please consider accepting one of the answer (the green tick mark on the left under the vote buttons). Your other request is a different question. I suggest you ask a new question for it, and yes attach the code and as much information as you can. It will always get you better help to show that you've tried by yourself first ;-)

Comment: Ok. I made a new question. Thank you for patience and for help!

Comment: Hey @jonasv2, thanks for the improvement to the function.

Answer (score -3):

Is that you want to do?

[image]

if so, you should set a background color for the axis

```
set(gca,'color','r')
```

and set the `facecolor` of the rectangle

```
r=rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','black','faceColor','black')
```

Hope this helps.