# Graph in a square in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

I have a matrix with 7 lines, which I upload automatically and generate a graph. I can't figure out, how I can represent it exactly in a square. My graph made by the matrix looks like this:

[image: graph]

This is the code which displays the matrix from my file:

```
reverse_matrix = flipud(matrix_to_display)
imagesc(reverse_matrix) 
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'2','4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14'})
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'33.60 cm','29.25 cm', '24.90 cm', '20.55 cm', '16.20 cm', '11.85 cm', '7.50 cm'})
```

How can I put the graph made by the matrix in the place of the white square?

[image]

And that is the code which create my matrix from the file

```
    array_step_one = zeros(1,14)
    array_step_two = zeros(1,14)
    array_line_matrix = zeros(1,14)
    final_matrix = cell(7)
    for index = 1:14
file_path = strcat('C:/StefanMatlab/1-4w/file', num2str(index))
file_path = strcat(file_path, '.txt');

fd_r = fopen(file_path, 'r')

content_info = fgets(fd_r)
content_info = fgets(fd_r)
content_info = fgets(fd_r)
content_info = fgets(fd_r)
content_info = fgets(fd_r)
content_info = fgets(fd_r)
temp_array = fscanf(fd_r, '%i')
for i = 1:14
    if mod(index,2) == 1
        array_step_one(i) = temp_array(i)
    else
        array_step_two(i) = temp_array(i)
    end
end
if mod(index , 2) == 0
    for j = 1 : 14
        if array_step_one(j) >= array_step_two(j)
            array_line_matrix(j) = array_step_one(j)
        else
            array_line_matrix(j) = array_step_two(j)
        end
    end
    array_step_one = zeros(1,14)
    array_step_two = zeros(1,14)
    for k = 1 : 14
        final_index = index / 2
        final_matrix{int16(final_index), k} = array_line_matrix(k)      
    end
end
    fclose(fd_r)
    end
```

Comment: Do you what your program detect this white rectangular automatically? Otherwise you could use xlim() and ylim()

Comment: My program create the matrix and generate a graph but the graph must be generated instead of white rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple workaround like the following?

```
matrix_to_display = ones(9,9,3);
a = rand(7,7,3);
matrix_to_display(2:8,2:8,:) = a;

reverse_matrix = flipud(matrix_to_display);
imagesc(reverse_matrix); 

set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'2','4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14'});
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'33.60 cm','29.25 cm', '24.90 cm', '20.55 cm', '16.20 cm', '11.85 cm', '7.50 cm'});
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

Check the following code.

```
clear all;

matrix_to_display = rand(7,7,3);

xlim = [0 8] ;
ylim = [0 8] ;
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim , .1, .1) ;
plot(X,Y,'k');
hold on ; grid off

reverse_matrix = flipud(matrix_to_display);
img = image(reverse_matrix); 

p = patch([.5 7.5 7.5 .5],[.5 0.5 7.5 7.5],'r');
set(p,'FaceAlpha',0);
```

Output:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Considering the suggestions from Hoki I updated the code as follows.

```
clear all;

matrix_to_display = rand(7,7);

xlim = [0 8] ;
ylim = [0 8] ;
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim , .1, .1) ;
plot(X,Y,'k');
hold on ; grid off

reverse_matrix = flipud(matrix_to_display);
img = imagesc(reverse_matrix); 
colormap('gray');

p = patch([.5 7.5 7.5 .5],[.5 0.5 7.5 7.5],'r');
set(p,'FaceAlpha',0);

set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'1', '2','4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '15'})
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'37.95 cm','33.60 cm','29.25 cm', '24.90 cm', '20.55 cm', '16.20 cm', '11.85 cm', '7.50 cm', '3.15 cm'})
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I must put my graph exactly like in this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949205/hatch-a-plot-in-matlab/30002092#30002092 But my graph must be generated instead of white rectangle.

Comment: @Hwathanie that's a good way to do it, but check your code, the `flipud` command errors on the 3D matrix. Just create a 2D matrix like in your first code, and use `imagesc` instead of `image`. Also just so the OP get a feel that this is what he's looking for, sending a `colormap('gray')` somewhere would help ;-).

Comment: @Hoki can you please give a try? Hwathanie shows exactly what I need but yours completations are perfectly. I'm novice in Matlab and sometimes I can't handle with it..

Comment: @Hoki, Thank you very much for your valuable inputs. I updated the code above based on your inputs. I was first trying to go ahead with matrix approach,  that is why I tried to have a 3 layer matrix, so that I can easily set the background color to white. I would actually like to recommend your answer on this, cos parameters are not hard-coded like in mine. Stefan, you are so demanding :(. If you too keep trying, we can reach a good answer always. :).

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved me! I succeed to finish my project!

Answer (score 2):

The solution hinted by Hwathanie is actually the simplest to implement if you have only 1 rectangle of image data to plot and if you can get away with readjusting your `X` and `Y` tick labels to show what you want on the axis labels.

Until he corrects his code, if you want to make it work, play a bit with his first code and his second code (and look at my comment on his answer, with all of that you should get somewhere).

I went with another approach which is more complex, but has the benefit to be more scalable. Basically I create a gridded patch with as many faces as you have points in your matrix, then I colour each face as the `imagesc` would colour an image. This `patch` object has the benefit of being movable and scalable, so I can directly insert it in place of your desired "rectangle", as you wanted in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949205/hatch-a-plot-in-matlab)

```
%// sample matrix data
nl = 7 ; nc = 14 ; nColor = 16 ;
cmap = gray(nColor) ;                   %// Pick a gray colormap (16 colors)
matrix_to_display = rand( nl , nc ) ;   %// random colors matrix
reverse_matrix = flipud(matrix_to_display);
figure ; colormap(cmap) ;               %// assign the gray colormap to the figure

%// Get the hatched background
xlim = [0 61] ; ylim = [0 45] ;
[X,Y] = hatch_coordinates( xlim , ylim ) ; %// this return coordinates to plot a hatch pattern
plot(X,Y,'k')                              %// and this simply plot the pattern, with the attributes you want (color, linespec, etc ...)
hold on ; grid off

%// *** THIS IS THE INTERESTING BIT ***
%// Define your rectangle patch 
pos = [3.75 5.6 53.5 29.5];  %// [x0 y0 W H] of your rectangle

fv = meshpatch( size(reverse_matrix) ) ;                            %// get the basic patch face grid
fv.vertices = bsxfun( @times , fv.vertices , [pos(3) pos(4) 1] ) ;  %// apply scale factor to vertices coordinates
fv.vertices = bsxfun( @plus , fv.vertices  , [pos(1) pos(2) 0] ) ;  %// apply offset to vertices coordinates

PatchFacesColors = rot90(reverse_matrix,-1) ;                       %// necessary to adjust color index to patch faces organisation
fv.facevertexcdata = PatchFacesColors(:) ;                          %// add "facevertexcdata" to the patch structure
hp = patch(fv,'FaceColor','flat','CDataMapping','scaled','EdgeColor','none') ; %// create the patch

%// refine axis
axis([0 61 0 45])
yt = [0 7.5 11.85 16.2 20.55 24.9 29.25 33.6 39.3 45].' ;
set( gca , 'Ytick' , yt , 'YTickLabel' , num2str(yt) )
```

[image: griddedpatch]

---

### CODE:

For the function `hatch_coordinates.m` can be found in this answer: [Hatch a plot in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29949205/hatch-a-plot-in-matlab/30002092#30002092)

for the function `meshpatch.m` is :

```
function fv = meshpatch( meshdim , normalized )
%// function fv = meshpatch( meshdim , normalised )
%//
%// return patch structure f.faces and f.vertices of a patch having the same
%// number of faces than the input size.

if nargin < 2 ; normalized = true ; end %// default option

nfx = meshdim(2) ; %// number of faces on X
nfy = meshdim(1) ; %// number of faces on X

%% // build patch vertices
x = (0:nfx).' * ones(1,nfy+1) ;    %'//ignore this comment
y = ones(nfx+1,1) * (0:nfy) ;
if normalized
    x = x ./ nfx ;
    y = y ./ nfy ;
end
fv.vertices = [x(:) y(:) zeros(numel(x),1) ] ;

%% // build patch faces
f0 = [1 2 nfx+3 nfx+2].' ;              %'// basic patch cell
fl = f0 * ones(1,nfx*nfy) ;             %// replicate to create all patch cell

%// now adjust the vertex indices to get all the cells rigth
cellAdd = bsxfun(@plus,(1:nfx).'*ones(1,nfy),(0:nfx+1:nfy*nfx))-1 ; 
fv.faces = bsxfun(@plus,fl, cellAdd(:).' ).' ; %// adjust indices of patch cell
```

Comment: It is perfect but I have a problem. With the code which I had created it imports automatically some values from a path file, creates a matrix and draws a graph and every value represent a percent like in my first picture from this question. That graph represent this [matrix](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajrgsnajk40j20c/matrix.png?dl=0) and I need also a legend. Unfortunately I can't use random colors because I have much more documents and every document will draw another graph..

Comment: @Ştefan, I could not replicate your matrix because in you code you gave it is read from a file (not available at the time), however I created the random matrix _exactly_ on the same model than the one you have, so just replace my matrix by yours and it should work.

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved me! I succeed to finish my project!