# If I have 4 coordinates making a rectangle, how can I color in that area?

Tags: matlab, colors, fill

I have 4 coordinates assigned to variables, so I would just like to colour in the rectangle that is created from these variables. I tried the fill function, but I cant gather much information from the example.

When I try to use:

`fill(bottom left point, top right point,'g')`

the figure it makes only shows a line between those points, and doesn't colour in the entire area.

I'm using MATLAB R2019b, if that helps.

Also, if its possible to fill the rectangle with a pattern instead, please let me know aswell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have  to specify the `X` and `Y` coordinated of all the vertices ([ref. to the fill documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html))

Comment: If you have a rectangle you can plot and fill it with [rectangle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html)

Comment: the `fill` command require more than bottom left/top right coordinate to work. It needs a full profile (only the last point is optional, Matlab will close the profile automatically). For rectangle with pattern inside I invite you to see this old answer: [Hatch a plot in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002092/3460361)