# Matlab: How to Fill an Area Between Two Lines with a Checkered or Lined Surface

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, fill

I am trying to fill the area between two lines with a checkered or lined "surface" in Matlab. I am currently using the `fill` command to display the area, however the area is displayed as a solid surface. What I am trying to do is to let the area appear as in the diagram presented below.

[image]

This is what I got so far:

[image]

My code currently in use:

```
x2 = [x, fliplr(x)];
inBetween = [Auf1_mW_pro_mg(1781:length(Auf1_mW_pro_mg)), fliplr(y_Temp)];
fill(x2, inBetween, 'g','facealpha',.5,'LineStyle','none');
```

Note : All the variables are vectors.

Does anybody know how to do this using the `fill` or another command?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you have any other option than 1) write a foor loop and calculate where from and to the lines shoudl go, then plot. 2) create a surface with the right shape, then plot with mesh()

Comment: Interesting question. Try some solutions from this site: https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/

Comment: If the link above does not work for you, you might get some inspiration from this: [Hatch a plot in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002092/3460361). It only does "squared" hatch patch at the moment but it wouldn't take mutch to adapt it for any shape.